# Examine search contain words

Tags: examine

I am trying to write script using examine fluent api.

I have conditions that I need to fulfill

- search must find nodes starting with searchTerm
- **search must find nodes containing searchTerm**
- search must find nodes ending with searchTerm
- search must support multiple words
- search must not fail due to & * ` and another characters

I am able to match only words starting with this string.

When I execute to code below, I do get only words starting with the searchTerm

```
   public IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> Search(string searchTerm)
        {
           //Create search Criteria
            var sc = ExamineManager.Instance.CreateSearchCriteria();

            //define query
            var query = sc.NodeName(searchTerm.MultipleCharacterWildcard())
                        .Or()
                        .Field("content", searchTerm.MultipleCharacterWildcard())
                        .Compile();


            var results = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ContentSearcher"].Search(query);                

            return results.OrderBy(x => x.Score).Select(MapSearchResults);
        }
```

**How do I update the search script for all conditions?**

Answer (score 1):

Solution with raw query.
This should hover
search must find nodes starting with searchTerm
search must find nodes containg searchTerm
search must find nodes ending with searchTerm
search must support multiple words

```
  var searchTerm = Request["term"].Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ExternalSearcher"];
          var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();
          var luceneString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
          luceneString.Append("nodeTypeAlias:");

          luceneString.Append("*");

          for (int i = 0; i < searchTerm.Length; i++)
          {

              luceneString.Append(" AND ");

              luceneString.Append("title:");
              luceneString.Append("*");
              luceneString.Append(searchTerm[i]);
              luceneString.Append("*");
          }

          var query = searchCriteria.RawQuery(luceneString.ToString());
          var searchResults = searcher.Search(query);
```

this article helped me http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html